# What's a good ASP & WCF host?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, hosting

Currently I'm new with ASP and WCF, but I really enjoy it and I would like to purchase some online hosting to get myself started.

Does anyone know a good hoster which isn't that expensive and supports WCF and ASP .NET MVC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just learning: Azure hosting is a nice choice. It would require you to learn a bit about Azure and cloud computing. However the documentation is good, it supports everything you are asking for, and your first 10 "small" web sites are free.

[Azure free trial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/)